# UIBezierPath containsPoint works only once

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uibezierpath

Following is my code to draw corners on the UITextView.

In .h file :

```
    @property(nonatomic,strong)  UIBezierPath *   upperLeft;
    @property(nonatomic,strong)  UIBezierPath *   upperRight;

-  (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

 upperLeft = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(xCorner + margin, yCorner + margin)
                                                   radius:5.5
                                               startAngle:0
                                                 endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(360)
                                                clockwise:YES];
        [[UIColor blackColor]setFill];
        [upperLeft fill];
        [upperLeft closePath];

upperRight = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(xCorner+ widths - margin, yCorner + margin)
                                                radius:5.5
                                            startAngle:0
                                              endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(360)
                                             clockwise:YES];
    [[UIColor blackColor]setFill];
    [upperRight fill];
    [upperRight closePath];
}

-  (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

     touchStart  =  [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

    isResizingUL = [upperLeft containsPoint:touchStart];
    isResizingUR= [upperRight containsPoint:touchStart];
}
```

When i tap on the path for the first time it gives the Bool value yes. But for later hits it gives value NO to any path.Even though hit at the path. Can anybody help me why is it happening so.

Comment: Are you using ARC? How are `upperLeft` and `upperRight` declared/defined?

Comment: Yes i am using ARC..UIBezierPath *   upperLeft;
 UIBezierPath *   upperRight; This is how i am declaring the paths in .h file. [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(xCorner+ widths - margin, yCorner + margin)
                                                radius:5.5
                                            startAngle:0
                                              endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(360)
                                             clockwise:YES];             this is the definition of the path.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to store upperLeft and lowerRight, but you're not using the property, and thus ARC won't be helping you by retaining the values.   Thus, when you fall out of scope, upperLeft and lowerRight are going to become undefined.  I'm a bit surprised it isn't crashing.

If you use `self.upperLeft=...` and `self.lowerRight=...`, you should have success.

Comment: Can you edit your original post to include the `.h` file declaration of the properties upperLeft and lowerRight?  You might also grab the bounding boxes from the upperLeft and lowerRight to make sure that they're where you expect them to be and log the touch location as well.

Comment: I added  NSLog(@"isResizingUL :%@",NSStringFromCGRect(upperLeft.bounds)); in touches begin for first time i am getting the valid values but for the second time i am getting as isResizingUL :{{inf, inf}, {0, 0}} why is this happening so?

Comment: (Please change the code in your question to reflect the `self.` assignment for future readers).   Based on the code, your drawRect is not complete up above.  Try logging the upperLeft.bounds and lowerRight.bounds at the end of your drawRect to see if you're getting called when you expect to.   Can you move the initialization of those variables somewhere outside of drawRect?   It is not uncommon for drawRect to be called with "unexpected" rectangles, so if you're calculating from that, that may explain it.